# Kotlin 1.3.72 Using andriod extention or should I change. Is it safe?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Good day.

I am somewhat new to kotlin and android development. I found a helpful guide from a few years ago it uses kotlin extensions which I have come to release is a bit outdated and no longer used. I built my app with this "old" code. Not upgrading my kotlin. The app works fine. It will be used as an inhouse app to manage some stuff. Is there a good reason for me to change to the new version of the code?

Thank you for all inputs and opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin will be [removed in Kotlin 1.8](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/discontinuing-kotlin-synthetics-for-views.html#:%7E:text=We%20are%20now%20setting%20a,the%20Kotlin%20Android%20Extensions%20plugin.) (expected at the end of 2022). At that time, you won’t be able to update your project to newer Kotlin versions if it still depends on the Kotlin Android Extensions plugin. Until then you're good but I suggest you migrate to View Binding as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about this.